# Problem in sciposter and \input command with figures

Tags: input, posters, sciposter

I'm making an a0 `sciposter` in LaTeX. I'm having problems when adding figures in tex+pdf files with the `\input` command. The problem is that the figure's text is too big for my figure. For example, the same figure in `beamer` (or a common LaTeX document) appears as the following image:

[image: Skeleton figure in beamer]

But the same image in my `sciposter` is as follows:

[image: Skeleton figure in sciposter]

The figure insertion code for both (`sciposter` and `beamer`/LaTeX) is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.90}{\input{Images/esqueleto.pdf_tex}}
    \caption{Esqueleto virtual de 15 articulaciones de \emph{OpenNI}/\emph{NITE}}                                                
\end{figure}
```

Is there any way to solve the problem and to generate the figure in the `sciposter` with the same proportions of the original image (in `beamer` for my example)?

---

The figure tex file is the next code (also for both, `sciposter` and `beamer`) exported from Inkscape:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.48.2, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'esqueleto.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{134.56256226bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,1.28819087)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{Images/esqueleto.pdf}}%
    \put(0.63961372,1.17326261){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Cabeza}}}%
    \put(0.78648125,0.90165272){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Torso}}}%
    \put(0.79518277,0.76070166){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Codo der.}}}%
    \put(0.81356486,0.50269197){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Mano der.}}}%
    \put(0.77404193,0.33459856){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Rodilla der.}}}%
    \put(0.72218005,0.07502538){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Pie der.}}}%
    \put(0.82068961,1.0126202){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Hombro der.}}}%
    \put(0.7226059,1.09835082){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Cuello}}}%
    \put(0.86809471,0.6181998){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Cadera der.}}}%
    \put(0.17688348,0.76070166){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Codo izq.}}}%
    \put(0.17148466,0.50269197){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Mano izq.}}}%
    \put(0.21519443,0.33459856){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Rodilla izq.}}}%
    \put(0.27034587,0.07502538){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Pie izq.}}}%
    \put(0.15482862,1.0126202){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Hombro izq.}}}%
    \put(0.13391934,0.61845517){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\scriptsize{Cadera izq.}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose two things:

1. Export your Inkscape file to PDF and use `\includegraphics{images/exportedPDFfile}`.
   That way the proportion graphic size to text size stays the same.
2. Redefine the `\scriptsize` macro that is used by Inkspace:

   ```
   \def\scriptsize{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}

   \documentclass{sciposter}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \scalebox{0.90}{\def\scriptsize{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}\input{esqueleto.tex}}
       \caption{Esqueleto virtual de 15 articulaciones de \emph{OpenNI}/\emph{NITE}}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
   ```

   Note that I put the redefinition inside the `\scalebox` macro so that it stays local.
   Instead of `\fontsize…` you could use any other already defined size macro:

   ```
   \let\scriptsize\tiny
   ```

Also: `\centering` and `\scriptsize` don't take any parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel I really really appreciate your help, the code \def\scriptsize{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont} did the trick.

Comment: @Herman `8` is the font size, `10` is the new `\baselineskip`. (You can [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).)

Comment: @Herman I wouldn't accept so fast. Give it some time. Maybe someone else will come up with a better answer.